# Finite axiom of choice in Munkres

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, induction, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In his book Munkres mentions that mathematicians have no qualms about using the finite axiom of choice:

Given a finite collection $\mathcal{A}$ of disjoint nonempty sets, there exist a set $C$ consisting of exactly one element from each element of $\mathcal{A}$.

However he dosen't give a proof of this fact (without using the axiom of choice). Is the following proof correct?

If $\mathcal{A}$ consists of only one set then we can pick any element $c$ from that set and let $C=\{c\}$.

Suppose the result holds for some $n$. We need to show that is holds also when $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,\dots A_n, A_{n+1}\}$. By hypothesis there exsit a set $C$ consisting of exactly one element from each element of $\{A_1,\dots A_n\}$. Let $c$ be any element of $A_{n+1}$ and let $C'=C\cup\{c\}$. Then $C'$ contains exactly one element from each element of $\mathcal{A}$.

By induction we have shown that the result holds for any finite collection $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: This is definitely the idea. Whether your proof is admissible or not in some formal system would depend on the formalism, which I assume Munkres does not employ because it is a topology book. But that is 100% the idea. (And, oddly enough, some mathematicians might very well have qualms with this, particularly if $n$ can be arbitrarily large. But again, it's a topology book.) Broadly speaking, most are OK with proofs that reference a finite number of choices from nonempty sets, even if the exact number of sets and exact nature of the choice are unspecified. And many of us are fine with AC too.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you. Isn't this the usual way to do an induction proof? What formalism do you refer to?

Comment: When people talk about mathematicians having "qualms" about methods of reasoning, usually one is getting deep into the foundations of mathematics and not the usual ways of doing things. That's all I meant.  Some people do not accept the existence of infinite sets, or choices made from infinite sets with no choice mechanism specified, etc. One can formalize systems where "the usual way" is not possible. Such people might reject your proof, or any use of induction that was not constrained in further ways. This has little to do with topology and more to do with foundations.

Comment: @leslietownes: Why are you bringing ultrafinitism into this question?

Comment: If the question is whether a proof is "correct" or what [all] "mathematicians" might have "no qualms" about, I think it potentially implicates the full spectrum of what people might regard as "correct," or what mathematicians might have no qualms about. I do think my comments also indicate that this issue is subsidiary to the point that Munkres is making and the soundness of the original poster's reasoning. Apologies if I fell over a tripwire there.

Comment: @leslietownes: That is the sort of nitpicking I'd expect to see on a mathematics website. **Q:** *"[Does everyone agree that this a chair?](https://imgur.com/gallery/nOmEk5S)"* **A:** *"No, because there is a person in rural Siberia who doesn't believe in chairs, so there's no consensus".*

Comment: @AsafKaragila We agree to disagree. I do think that my comments are not remotely as contrary or absolutist as your example. But I appreciate the input and will moderate my tone in the future.

Comment: @leslietownes: I was exaggerating to make a point, and it seems to have worked. So we can move on.